# Gradle build fail - Capacitor

Tags: android, gradle, capacitor

I am currently trying to build a web app for mobile using capacitor, during the build I encounter these errors which does not seem to be linked to capacitor but rather to gradle :

```
[Ionic] Running...
> pnpm exec cap run android --target=Pixel_7_Pro_API_33  --external --no-sync --public-host=XXX-XXX-XX-X
× Running Gradle build - failed!
[error] 
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        
        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
        > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
        > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1.
        Required by:
        project :
        > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1.
        > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom'.
        > Read timed out
        > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
        Required by:
        project :
        > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
        > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.4.0/google-services-4.4.0.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.4.0/google-services-4.4.0.pom'.
        > Read timed out
        
        * Try:
        > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
        > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        > Run with --scan to get full insights.
        > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
        
        BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s
        
[error] pnpm exec cap run android --target=Pixel_7_Pro_API_33  --external --no-sync --public-host=XXX-XXX-XX-X Failed
[error] Android Failed.
```

my gradle target : Oracle OpenJDK version 19.0.2 > downgraded to JDK 17

my gradle properties at project level :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    } }

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    } }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir  
}
```

**What I tried :**

Removed/Commented proxy settings in gradle.properties (i'm behind corporte proxy, but currently at home)

Removed proxy settings in android studio :
Appearance & Behavior > System settings > Http proxy
Check connection is successful with `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom`

Access directly to `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom` with a navigator and it work

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The latest officially supported OpenJDK version for Android Studio is JDK 17. This information is available on the official Android developer website: https://developer.android.com/build/jdks

Comment: Just tried to downgrade to JDK 17 and the problem persist

Comment: Check the project level gradle, 

repositories {
  google()
}

This line must be there...if missing, please added it..

Comment: I added the content of the gradle in my initial post, this info is already present :/

Answer (score 0):

Just found a gradle.properties under C:\Users\Session.gradle with proxy settings. removed it and the project build correctly.